# Generic Implementation of Requesting the Permission -MarshMallow-Android

Tags: android, oop

I was developing an app that reads Excel files form external storage 
the problem i was facing was the permission to be added in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i have added the permission in the manifest but problem was still the same 
i've searched a lot but everyone answered that add permission in your manifest

then at Developer portal of android i've find out that for MarshMallow you to get the permission pragmatically in that activity  like this

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
    }
}
```

and then in result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
      switch (requestCode) {
         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
             if (grantResults.length > 0
                  && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted, yay! Do the
            // contacts-related task you need to do.

        } else {

            // permission denied, boo! Disable the
            // functionality that depends on this permission.
        }
        return;
    }

    // other 'case' lines to check for other
    // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

i want a generic method to be used for such permissions in the Application 
i just have to pass the method and the permission i want 
i don't want to include this code in every activity where i want any permission